# Set maximum forms can be opened (the exe file can be opened 4 times only)

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can I set Maximum forms (exe file) can be opened

(I want to set the exe file can be opened 4 times Only!)

`MessageBox("You have already opened This exe file 4 times";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this one:

```
Dim instanceCount As Integer = Process.GetProcessesByName("yourexename").Count()
If instanceCount > 4 then
    MessageBox("You have already opened This exe file 4 times")
    Environment.Exit(0)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the running processes in C# by calling `Process.GetProcessesByName("YourApplicationName")` and check if there are greater than 4 processes running. If there are, show your MessageBox and then quit the current instance of the application.